# Why is Swiper not working for me in VUEJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli, swiper.js

Hi I am trying to use Swiper in vue cli but it does not work for me.
I'm reading the official documentation and it doesn't seem like anything is wrong, I tried copying and pasting and it didn't work either. https://swiperjs.com/vue

```
  <template>
        <div>
            <Swiper :slides-per-view="4" :space-beetween="50">
                <SwiperSlide>SLIDE 1</SwiperSlide>
                <SwiperSlide>SLIDE 2</SwiperSlide>
                <SwiperSlide>SLIDE 3</SwiperSlide>
                <SwiperSlide>SLIDE 4</SwiperSlide>
            </Swiper>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
        import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue';
        export default{
            name: 'Swiper',
            components: {
                Swiper,
                SwiperSlide
            }
        }
    </script>
```

It gives me this error:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4484 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at isWhitespace (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2533)
at Array.every (<anonymous>)
at resolveSlots (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2525)
at initRender (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3485)
at VueComponent.Vue._init (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5003)
at new VueComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5154)
at createComponentInstanceForVnode (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3283)
at init (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3114)
at createComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5978)
at createElm (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5925)
```

Comment: Don't name your component/page `name: 'Swiper',` by doing so when you call `<Swiper>` vue thinks its self, so recursively calls itself, rtm: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#name

Comment: Thanks, once I modify the indicated thing I stop showing that error, but now it shows me this: vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <Swiper>
       <SwiperCategorias> at src/components/Swiper.vue
         <Productos> at src/views/Productos.vue
           <App> at src/App.vue
             <Root>

Comment: np, is different issue

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because you're not initializing the Swiper.

Try to add this code on your setup :

```
const swiper = ref();

    function init(instance) {
      swiper.value = instance;
    }
```

Don't forget to return the function init.

Then add this to your Swiper component:

```
@swiper="init"
```

Like this:

```
            <Swiper
            class="w-full flex items-center justify-center"
            grab-cursor
            update-on-window-resize
            navigation
            :pagination="{ clickable: true }"
            :scrollbar="{ draggable: true }"
            :slides-per-view="isMobile ? 1 : 2"
            @swiper="init"
          >
```